# How does one go about partial updates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How does one go about partial updates (i.e. via `PATCH`)? `rake routes` indicates that `def update` handles `PUT` and `PATCH`. This is how my Rails API is setup:

```
@user.first_name = user_params[:attributes][:'first-name']
@user.last_name = user_params[:attributes][:'last-name']
```

In `user` model. Both `first_name` and `last_name` have `validates … presence: true`. However, client, is trying to hit the endpoint with just `attributes[first-name]`. Note, `attributes[last-name]` is not being passed in the request. Rails thinks that `@user.first_name` has a value, but `@user.last_name` is `nil`. So a validation error is thrown

One way I thought of going about this was something like:

```
@user.first_name = user_params[:attributes][:'first-name'].present? ? user_params[:attributes][:'first-name'] : @user.first_name
@user.last_name = user_params[:attributes][:'last-name'].present? ? user_params[:attributes][:'last-name'] : @user.last_name
```

Is this a viable approach? Or is there something better I can consider?

**EDIT**. A more sophisticated problem is when I need to pre-calculate before actually saving the object. Take for example a product trying to update its price against a discount value, if present

```
def update
  product                        = Product.find(params[:id])
  product.amount_in_cents        = product_params[:attributes][:'amount-in-cents']
  product.discount_in_percentage = product_params[:attributes][:'discount-in-percentage'].present? ? product_params[:attributes][:'discount-in-percentage'].to_f : nil # Can be 0.10

  if product.discount_in_percentage.present?
    product.amount_in_cents = product.amount_in_cents + (product.amount_in_cents * product.discount_in_percentage)
  else
    product.amount_in_cents = product.amount_in_cents
  end

  if product.save
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, we have a convention that the attributes in Model should be fetched to the Rails App like `user[first_name]` , `user[last_name]` and in controller we build a private method like `users_params` which will represent the data to be fed to the `User` model. like

```
# in controller
def update
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.update(users_params)
end

private

# This will prepare a whitelisted params data
def users_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, ...)
end
```

### No need of this

```
@user.first_name = user_params[:attributes][:'first-name'].present? ? user_params[:attributes][:'first-name'] : @user.first_name
@user.last_name = user_params[:attributes][:'last-name'].present? ? user_params[:attributes][:'last-name'] : @user.last_name
```

---

In your case, you need to reformat the params keys to `first_name` instead of `first-name` and so forth. This will help you do your stuff with ease.

> Tip: Try to keep it simpler as possible

Comment: I made an edit. Simply doing `foobar.update(foobar_params)` wont if some pre-calculation needs to be done before the actual `update`. Looking forward to your feedback